# Список пользователей в Одноклассниках по указанному городу

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

Кто-нибудь знает как получить список пользователей (их id) в [одноклассниках](https://ok.ru) по указанному городу?
Через API или как-то по-другому?
Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Читайте про API одноклассников (Если оно вообще существует).

Comment: @MrBin оно есть, но метода, котор0ый бы позволял получить список пользователей по указанному городу я не нашел. Поэтому и спрашиваю